# how to make image maintain aspect ratio in div

Tags: javascript, html

The picture within the collapsible banner has a skewed aspect ratio upon loading. Only when the "click me" button is pressed will it change to the desired size. The desired effect is that the photo maintains its aspect ratio. I suspect it is something to do with the javascript but I know nothing about javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

Jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eno34cxp/

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
          coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = this.nextElementSibling;
            if (content.style.display === "block") {
              content.style.display = "none";
            } else {
              content.style.display = "block";
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: Try removing `display: flex` and other flex properties from `div.collapsible-content` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div.collapsible-content {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* display: flex; */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Remove `display: flex;` since it's a duplicate within that snippet.

Comment: That did the trick! Can't believe that was the answer, thanks very much!

Comment: @clearblueskies Glad that helped u! Why don't u vote up my answer for me kindly? :)